# Optimal thread pool size in android

Tags: android

I got an app that got a lot of remote resource loading actions, scheduled runnables and other OS events handling.
I'm using a single executor service with cached threads. 
I have no idea how many threads should I use for optimal performance and battery usage.

Is there a way to know?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you do not need to worry about number of threads affecting battery usage. Because if the amount of work is the same (lets say in terms of CPU instructions) there should be not much difference in battery drain if you do it on one thread or in parallel using 2 threads. You will have your result faster, but CPU will still execute *almost* same number of instructions.

As for performance gains, if thread consuming cpu 100% of a time, then having more threads, than amount of Cores wont make any performance difference, actually you will get a little bit less performance because of scheduling overhead.

You should define a metric to evaluate performance, and define what is "optimal" for you. It is really hard to say not knowing what software is doing exactly. And if there is no performance/battery issue right now, then there is probably no need to worry about it.

Your question cant have definitive answer because it is very broad.